# Iterate though quadtree children

Tags: c#, recursion, xna

I would like to recursively check the children of all a root node in a quadtree.

The code below would result in all the child nodes being returned however it is not possible to add elements to an collection while iterrating through it (sadly)

```
foreach (QuadTree tree in trees)
        {
            if (tree.Children.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach(QuadTree child in tree.Children)
                {
                    trees.Add(child);
                }
            }
        }
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do one pass first gathering all the `child` objects you want to add and storing them in a local `List<QuadTree>`, then add those items after your `foreach` loop. EDIT: But this _seems_ kind of weird to me; you're iterating the children's children in your `trees`, then adding them to the root `trees` collection?

Comment: Note: since `QuadTree` is your class you can enable modification during `foreach`. It is up to you to figure out how such operation should behave (and how to explain/remember non-standard behavior of such class)

Comment: @alexei how do I accomplish this?

Comment: You could just iterate using the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, using the index and just adding to the end of the list I came up with this.

```
       int max = trees.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            QuadTree tree = trees[i];
            if (tree.Children.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach(QuadTree child in tree.Children)
                {
                    trees.Add(child);
                }
            }
            max = trees.Count;
        }
```